# Store and remote filtering

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a store where I want to set a filter in the beforequery event.

The problem is when I do it like this

```
store.addFilter({property:'name', value: 'xxx'});
```

the actuall addFilter call will send a request, which is a problem because it will fire the beforequery event again.

So I add the supresevent parameter to the function call

```
store.addFilter({property:'name', value: 'xxx'}, true);
```

but, in this case the request doesn't have the filter param at all.

Am I missing something ?

All I want to is to add a filter in a beforequery event and the let it do a request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a property on the store called `autoFilter`. Set it to false. It's a private property, therefore it's not in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with a problem in a similar context. I wanted to set a filter upon the store using the `setFilter()` method. But using this method I had encountered that the store triggered the load event twice. One request included the filter parameters, the other one didn't.

**Request1:**

[image]

**Request2:**

[image]

This behavior resulted in wrong information in my component. After a while of tinkering I encountered that I can bypass the `setFilter()` method by invoking the [filter()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) method of the store directly.

**Grid-Code:**

```
...
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.callParent(arguments);
    me.getStore().filter([
        {
            property: someProperty,
            value: someValue
        }
    ]);
},
...
```

Applying the filter this way has solved the issue for me. I hope this will help you as well.